# how to bind the values of two different arrays with each other in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

hi i'm going to manage the user access levels with angular js and json.
i have two arrays one for menu structure and the other for access levels.

> current access levels :

```
    $scope.current_access_levels ={
      "can_home":{"title":"home","value":true},
      "can_mail":{"title":"mail","value":false}
    };
```

> menu structure :

```
    $scope.menu = [
      {"id":"1","name":"home","aclvl":"can_home"},
      {"id":"2","name":"mail","aclvl":"can_mail"}
    ];
```

every menu field has an "aclvl" that matches with the names of objects in "current_access_level"  array.

> what i'm going to do is something like this :

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
      <div  ng-repeat="aclvl in current_access_levels">
        <label>{{aclvl.title}}</label><input type="checkbox" value="1" ng-model="aclvl.value"/>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="men in menu">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="current_access_levels.(men.aclvl).value"/>{{men.aclvl}}
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

for example if the "aclvl" of "men" is equal to "can_home" the checkbox value should be equal to "aclvl.can_home.value".
any body knows how should i handle this!?
i have added a fiddle to clear what i'm supposing to do.
thanks

```js
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
  
    $scope.current_access_levels ={"can_home":{"title":"home","value":true},"can_mail":{"title":"mail","value":false}};

    $scope.menu = [{"id":"1","name":"home","aclvl":"can_home"},{"id":"2","name":"mail","aclvl":"can_mail"}];
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <!-- current access levels -->
  <p>current access levels</p>
  <div  ng-repeat="aclvl in current_access_levels">
    <label>{{aclvl.title}}</label><input type="checkbox" value="1" ng-model="aclvl.value"/>
  </div>
  <!-- current access levels -->
  <br />
    <div>{{current_access_levels}}</div>
  <br />
  <hr>
  <!-- menu structure just for example -->
  <p>menu structure</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="men in menu">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="current_access_levels.can_home.value"/>{{men.aclvl}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- menu structure just for example -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="men in menu">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="current_access_levels.can_home.value"/>{{men.aclvl}}
    </li>`
You have two checkboxes bound to the same model (they both reference the same variable)

Comment: tnx for your answer, i know that. it's an example to show what i'm going to do. i want to do it with the "ng-repeat" for each field of menu. each field of menu has a "ac_lvl" that should be in "current_access_levels.here.value"

Comment: thanks for Shailendra Singh Deol answer. that's the correct way of do it and it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` with `current_access_levels` it like as -

```
 <li ng-repeat="men in menu">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="current_access_levels[men.aclvl].value"/>{{men.aclvl}}
    </li>
```

Comment: thank you very much it works like a charm now. i can't vote right now cause of my reputation. excuse me.